# Using Azure function CLI 2x to create EvenHubTrigger

Tags: azure-functions, eventtrigger, azure-functions-core-tools

I try to migrate Azure function EventHubTrigger 1x to 2x. But, My Azure function CLI 2x cant binding my Trigger and my output is `No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public..` This is my project
[image]
I don't know what config I miss

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's no binding in your code. First you miss the `Function` Binding as well as there is no `Trigger` binding. So here's a simple example for EventHubTriggered Azure Function

```
public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "ConnectionString")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

                // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
            }

        }
    }
```